# Key value datastructure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a google map where user places markers at various locations. I show a jquery dialog on click event which has a form, where user will fill other details pertaining to the marker.
Now i need to make this data persist:

1] I need to store the markers ( along with the details ) to a hidden field of a form, so my server can parse it and populate the database. Something on the line of:

```
markerData = JSON.stringify($('#dialog' + markerId).serializeObject()); // the form
.. add the markerData with key as markerId to a global javascript variable ..
$('#markersList').val( JSON.stringify("the global var"));
```

Note:
   `$('#dialog' + markerId)` will uniquely identify the markers dialog(which has the form)

2] I need to retrieve the values from the database and form the string that will be placed in the hidden field. This is required for the edit/view page.

Basically i need a datastructure(key/value) in javascript where markerId is the key and the form elements are the values, AND i need a way to convert all the values in a format parsable by server (via hidden field) and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
var keyValuePairs = [{ "key1": "value1" }, { "keyN": "valueN" }];
alert(keyValuePairs["key1"]);
```

Or just:

```
var keyValuePairs = {};
keyValuePairs["key1"] = "value1";
keyValueParis["keyN"] = "value2";
alert(keyValuePairs["key1"]);
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to post this associative array as JSON in a hidden field, just *stringify* the array with the JSON library of your choice and set JSON text to the whole hidden field.

Comment: Please don't use `new Array()` for associative arrays `{}` should be used instead.

Comment: @Shurdoof, any reason there? Or it's just your opinion..?

Comment: Thanks Matias, however i need to store all the values ("value1","valueN") in a hidden field in a way so that i can parse it on server side and populate the db. ( i am using php )

Comment: So just "stringify" with JSON library your associative array whenever data or controls change their values or options in the UI and you got it.

Comment: Or a better version: before posting your page back to the server, stringify your associative array, and set it to the whole hidden field.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer, For example `var a = new Array(); a["length"] = "aaa"` throws an error, also it just adds overhead.

Comment: @Shurdoof I can't check this behaves this way, so I'll update and add "{}" instead of "new Array()". Maybe I'm wrong, but I used to do that way and I had no problems.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer, usually it will work just fine, but there is just no reason to create an array if you need an object.

Comment: @Shurdoof but this case seems to be more an "array" than an object. After all, it's a key-value pair collection, that's why both examples are using arrays instead of objects. By the way, you know how JavaScript handles objects...

Comment: "a key-value pair collection" - that's what any object in JS is

Comment: @Michael There're some points of views to define the same thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

All objects in javascript are key/value pairs. What else do you need? You can have it like that:

Define a variable

```
var userInput = {}
```

as soon as for given `markerId` you have `formElements` specified, just do

```
userInput[markerId] = formElements
```

It is the same as if you'd have a concrete Id when writing your code (say `Id1`) and write

```
userInput.Id1 = formElements
```

So after that you have `userInput` object with property names equal to your ids (keys), and values equal to user defined form elements - exactly what you need, right?